# Tying Contributions to Events

Tags: civievent, contributions

I'm trying to attach an event to a contribution that I enter by hand. I see that the "source" field is where I need to do that. I've been entering the name of the event into the source field but my totals in the revenue report are still zero for the event. Is there a way that the source can be a drop down of events to choose from or is it a matter of using the exact naming of the event in the source field?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this a registration for the event, or you got the contribution at/from the event and you're trying to note that somewhere?

Comment: Thanks- The client did not set up donations/registration for the event and has to enter the contributions by hand. They want the event report to reflect the total that is entered in by hand. They have entered in the name of the event into the source of the contribution form but the event report is still zero.

Comment: I'm afraid the source field is just a text field, it doesn't actually create a link from the contribution to the event.

Answer (score 2):

The link internally between a contribution and a contribution page or an event is not something you can edit via the web interface. The only way would be to directly edit the database data via an SQL query. This is the type of thing you would need to hire a developer to do, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a link or term that I can google search to get some info on editing the civicrm database to link a contribution and event?

Comment: @crawpx Changing things directly in the database is not a recommended route for someone who doesn't know enough about databases to work out for themselves what changes need to be made and how to do it. You should either hire a developer or use a UI work-around. ( I have givem one in my answer, but other people may have other suggestions)

Answer (score 2):

As a UI work-around for this particular event, I would probably create a campaign type Event and a campaign with the event name and details. Contributions can then be linked to the campaign when you enter them and you can run reports to find the total contributions for the campaign.